# Atmel32 - ADC and PWM stuck in while loop under UART

Tags: c, embedded

I'm writing code to run commands in string format over UART from a computer using terminal emulator, the code works fine. All commands run normally as expected, but it's stuck in "smarton" command which enable ADC to output the reading to PWM (i.e. LED brightness is controlled by a photoresistor). The "smarton" command runs normally but doesn't allow for any other command to run following it. Is there a way to keep it running and move to other command or even terminate it and switch to other option.

```
#include <string.h>
#include "STD_TYPES.h"
#include "BIT_MATH.h"
#include "DIO_interface.h"
#include "PORT_interface.h"
#include "ADC_interface.h"
#include "TIMER_interface.h"
#include "TIMER_register.h"
#include "USART_interface.h"

char password[]="1234";
char fanon[]="fanon";
char fanoff[]="fanoff";
char opendoor[]="opendoor";
char closedoor[]="closedoor";
char smarton[]="smarton";

int Str[8];
u16 App_u16ADCReading;
void main (void)
{
    PORT_voidInit();      //Rx input (PD0) and Tx output (PD1)
    TIMER1_voidInit();
    ADC_voidInit();
    ICR1 = 2048;
    USART_voidInit();
    UART_Send_String("UART Module Initialized and Active");
    USART_voidSend('\n');
    USART_voidSend('\r');
    pin_check();
    UART_Send_String("                   List of commands        ");
    USART_voidSend('\n');
    USART_voidSend('\r');
    UART_Send_String("fanon   fanoff    opendoor    closedoor      smarton");
    USART_voidSend('\n');
    USART_voidSend('\r');
    UART_Send_String("Smart_Home>>");
    
    while(1)
    {
        gets_UART1(Str);
        USART_voidSend('\r');        //carriage return
        USART_voidSend('\n');
        UART_Send_String("Smart_Home>>");

        if((strncmp(Str, fanon, 5))==0)
        {
            DIO_u8SetPinValue (DIO_u8PORTA, DIO_u8PIN1, DIO_u8PIN_HIGH);  //fan ON;
        }

        else if((strncmp(Str, fanoff, 6))==0)
        {
            DIO_u8SetPinValue (DIO_u8PORTA, DIO_u8PIN1, DIO_u8PIN_LOW); //fan OFF;
        }

        
        if((strncmp(Str, opendoor, 8))==0)
        {
            Servo_Motor(90); //open door;
        }
        else if((strncmp(Str, closedoor, 9))==0)
        {
            Servo_Motor(0); //close door;
        }
        if((strncmp(Str, smarton, 7))==0)
        {
        do {
            ADC_u8StartConversionSynch(SINGLE_ENDED_ADC2, &App_u16ADCReading); //Synchronous mode
            OCR1B = App_u16ADCReading;   //output digital value to PWM 
            }
            while((strncmp(Str, smarton, 7))==0);
        }
    }
}

/* Servo Motor (Limited) function using Timer1
 * Argument: angle in degrees between 0 to 180  */
void Servo_Motor(u8 rotation_angle)
{
    ICR1 = 19999;
    OCR1A = 449 + ((2050/180) * rotation_angle);   //output is on OC1A which is pin PD5
}

void pin_check (void)
{
    u8 trials=0;
    do
    {
        UART_Send_String("Enter PIN: ");
        gets_UART1(Str);   //get password
        if((strncmp(Str, password, 4))==0)
        {
            UART_Send_String("Welcome to Smart Home Application");
            USART_voidSend('\n\r');
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            trials++;
            UART_Send_String("Wrong password, please try again - remaining trials: ");
            USART_voidSend('\n\r');
        }
    }while(trials<3);

    if (trials==3)
    {
        UART_Send_String("Account locked !!");
        for(;;);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OfCourse will stuck after the condition of smarton be true , Because you inside if condition put you check same condition inside do--while(the same condition "And It is True Condition Always and will stay implement the code inside 'do' ") like this your code go inside infinit loop .

```
if((strncmp(Str, smarton, 7))==0)
    {
    do {
        ADC_u8StartConversionSynch(SINGLE_ENDED_ADC2, &App_u16ADCReading); //Synchronous mode
        OCR1B = App_u16ADCReading;   //output digital value to PWM 
        }
        while((strncmp(Str, smarton, 7))==0); 
    }
```

--------------------------------------- > Solution <------------------------------------

you need to change the do-while condition for example :

```
if((strncmp(Str, smarton, 7))==0)
    {
    do {
        ADC_u8StartConversionSynch(SINGLE_ENDED_ADC2, &App_u16ADCReading); 
        OCR1B = App_u16ADCReading;   //output digital value to PWM 
        gets_UART1(Str); // try to get new str with every looping and check it to out from this infinit loop . 
                           
        }
        while((strncmp(Str, smarton, 7))==0); 
    }
```

I wish that my unswer can help you .

Comment: Just swap `if` for `while`.

Comment: Calling gets_UART1(Str) function inside while loop gets only one reading of ADC. What actually required is to keep ADC/PWM running in the background and call gets_UART1(Str) function for other commands

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is to keep ADC/PWM in while (1) loop and to enable interrupt-based transmission of UART instead of polling mode

```
    while(1)
    {
        ADC_u8StartConversionSynch(SINGLE_ENDED_ADC2, &App_u16ADCReading);  //ADC Synchronous mode - LDR
        if (light_flag==1)
        {
            OCR1B = App_u16ADCReading-384;   //output is on OC1B which is pin PD4
        }

        else if(light_flag==0)
        {
            OCR1B = 0;                       //output is on OC1B which is pin PD4
        }
        UARTINT_voidSetCallBack(&get_input);
    }
void get_input(void)
{
    gets_UART1(Str);
    if((strncmp(Str, smartlighton, 12))==0)
    {
        light_flag=1;
        USART_voidSend('\r');        //carriage return (to print a new line)
        USART_voidSend('\n');
        UART_Send_String("Smart_Home>>");
    }
}
```